# How to set particular value to the address location contain in pointer variable?

Tags: delphi

I have a pointer variable Value and i need to set 0 at the address location hold by value.

```
function Setvalto(Value :Pointer);
begin
Value:=0;
end;
```

above code might change the address hold by pointer variable but i want to set zero at the address hold by Value.

Comment: `Set` is a keyword, and `Value:=0;`should not compile either. The function does not have a result type either, so it is very unlikely that this is your actual code. Please **always** show the real code, not some made up typed-into-the-browser pseudo-code. That might also help giving a useful answer. The answer given is correct ,but obviously there is a difference between your code and the code in the answer. Again: **always show your real code**, if possible a [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must know **type** of data addressed by that pointer.

For example, for `short` you can cast pointer to right type and make

```
PShort(Value)^ := 42;
```

In this case outer data addressed by this pointer will be changed.

---

Also note that changing `Value` itself inside this procedure does not influence on outer variable because argument is passed "by value"

And `function` needs result type

Full working example:

```
var
  sh: short;
  p: Pointer;

procedure SetShort(Value :Pointer);
begin
  PShort(Value)^ := 42;
  Value:= nil;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('inside %p', [Value]));
end;

begin
  sh := 1;
  p := @sh;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('before %d %p', [sh, p]));
  SetShort(p);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('after %d %p', [sh, p]));
```

Result:

```
before 1 0018F56E
inside 00000000
after 42 0018F56E
```

Comment: type of data is short

Comment: thank you for answer but  it's giving access violation error

Comment: Answer does not give AV, but your code (yet invisible for us) can.

Comment: What type is a *short*? *Shortint* (8 byte signed)? *Smallint* (16 byte signed, like C short)?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis   `SHORT = Smallint;`

Comment: @MBo: Yeah, found it in Winapi.Windows.